# galleria thumbnail nav always display

Tags: galleria

I'm trying to get the arrows either side of the thumbnail navigation to display all the time, but at the opacity stated (disabled = 0.2) and enabled (0.8). I have tried messing with the galleria classic css but that didn't work..

any ideas?

Comment: The thumbnail navigation arrows seem to be displayed all the time in the Classic Demo http://galleria.aino.se/media/galleria/src/themes/classic/classic-demo.html

Comment: good point I never noticed that! I'll take a look at that code, thanks very much

Comment: I added a background colour to the nav and it works great now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a background colour to the thumbnail navigation buttons and they are now visible all the time but with the same opacity's.

Answer (score 2):

You can unbind the hover functionality and set the opacity of the nav elements to 1.

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    extend: function() {
        this.$('image-nav-left, image-nav-right').unbind('hover');
        this.$('image-nav-left, image-nav-right').animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Finally I found the answer! Thanks! :) But why do you apply `animate()` then? Unbinding is enough, isn't it?